# How to set custom stop words for sklearn CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm trying to run LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) on a non-English text dataset.

From sklearn's tutorial, there's this part where you count term frequency of the words to feed into the LDA:

```
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,
                            max_features=n_features,
                            stop_words='english')
```

Which has built-in stop words feature which is only available for English I think. How could I use my own stop words list for this?

Comment: oh my, yeah it worked! should've read the documentation better next time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may just assign a `list` of your own words to the `stop_words`, e.g.:

```
stop_words = (["word1", "word2","word3"])
```

Comment: Why a frozenset and not just a list? According to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) a list is enough

Comment: @nivalderramas Yeah, my link does not work now, previously, it showed the source code where `frozenset` was used.