# How to force sklearn CountVectorizer to not remove special characters (i.e. #, @, , $ or %)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is my code:

```
count = CountVectorizer(lowercase = False)

vocabulary = count.fit_transform([words])
print(count.get_feature_names())
```

For example if:

```
 words = "Hello @friend, this is a good day. #good."
```

I want it to be separated into this:

```
['Hello', '@friend', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'day', '#good']
```

Currently, this is what it is separated into:

```
['Hello', 'friend', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'day']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `token_pattern` parameter here from `CountVectorizer` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

Pass a regex to tell CountVectorizer what should be considered a word. Let's say in this case we tell CountVectorizer, even words with `#` or `@` should be a word. Then do:

```
count = CountVectorizer(lowercase = False, token_pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9$&+,:;=?@#|<>.^*()%!-]+')
```

Output:

```
['#good', '@friend', 'Hello', 'a', 'day', 'good', 'is', 'this']
```

Comment: Also, how would I force CountVectorizer to ignore certain words? If words was:

`words = “Hello @friend, this is a good day https://www.google.com/. #good."`

I want it to still be separated into:


`['Hello', 'friend', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'day']`

Without the URL.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can pass another parameter called stop_words and assign the list of words to be ignored. Please check the documentation link I posted, it is written there :)

Comment: Here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124476/how-to-set-custom-stop-words-for-sklearn-countvectorizer

Comment: Is there any way I could set the parameter such that it would remove any string containing `https` in order to remove any URL that appeared.? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You can clean your string first by removing all https links doing: `words = re.sub(r"\bhttps:\//[a-z0-9.]*", '', words)` and then go ahead with the usual solution. :)